# Azure Container Instances outgoing IP ranges

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-container-instances

I'd like to generate an Azure Storage V2 SAS-Token that limits its allowed IP addresses to those from Azure Container Instances located in a give Azure Region. I do not see any indication of these IP ranges anywhere.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#parameters-common-to-account-sas-and-service-sas-tokens

Comment: Or you mean you can't find outgoing ips?

Comment: If you mean to restrict the access IP range in the Azure Storage V2 SAS-Token, you can see it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#shared-access-signature-parameters).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Tried all those before I asked here. 1. The official link file for IPs from Azure does not appear to list IPs for docker container instances? 2. Yes, I can easily set an IP in the SAS, but I don't have this IP until after the docker container is deployed in Azure, and then I can't set it anymore (e.g. in docker env_file) since the container is already deployed - chicken and egg problem. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Yes, IPs outgoing from the Azure Docker Container instances, ingoing then to Azure Storage Container used by the Docker Container.

Comment: I think all the container instance public IPs are chosen from Azure Public IP range. I don't think your way is good. If you do not want to deny all Azure service, it's better to restrict the public IPs which your container instances have used.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @GGleGrand I mean that all Azure services access the Internet or be accessed from the Internet through Azure Public IPs. And for Container Instance, the public IP is a random one from the Azure Public IPs. How can you restrict a random IP? It means you will restrict all Azure services if you restrict the Azure Public IP Range. I suggest you restrict the exact public IP of the ACI instead of the IP range.

Answer (score 1):

These are the official links for IP ranges in Azure.

Public: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519
US Gov: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57063
Germany: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57064
China: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57062

Comment: @GGleGrand, did you find this answer useful? I don't know how to use list of those IPs as the Azure Container Instances section is not present.

Comment: you'd have to whitelist all the ranges of the region, i'm afraid. @JakubZłoczewski

Comment: there must be way to specify which IPs are for container instances, I don't want to whitelist whole region ...

Comment: what makes you think thats the case? @JakubZłoczewski

Comment: I shouldn't use word "must". To me it sounds like basic feature - for example AzureKeyVault, AzureMachineLearning have short list of own IPs

Comment: I'm not aware of such a list.

Comment: Link seems outdated.